# addObserver in main thread using GCD and post notification in a global thread but the method never be called

Tags: ios, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch, nsnotification

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //NSNotificationCenter第一坑

    NSLog(@"current thread:%@",[NSThread currentThread]);

    //在主线程中注册通知并转发消息
    //add observer in main thread and deal in main thread

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        NSLog(@"current thread:%@",[NSThread currentThread]);
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(handleNotification:) name:@"notificaiton_1" object:nil];
    });

    //在子线程中发送通知
    //post notification in another thread not in the same thread as main

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^{

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"notificaiton_1" object:nil];

    });


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
//and this method never be called 
- (void)handleNotification:(NSNotification *)notification{
    //处理通知
    //handle notification here

    NSLog(@"current thread:%@",[NSThread currentThread]);

    NSLog(@"handle notification");

}
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this? The most common practice is post the notification in Main thread...

Comment: yeah,post a notification in main thread maybe a good practice ! but i want wo know NSNotification's implement theory and why the - (void)handleNotification:(NSNotification *)notification method not be called .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to know queue & thread are totally different concepts. A queue may run across several threads.

Second, if you post a notification on a thread, the observers are called on that thread.

So according to your codes handleNotification is definitely not called.